# how to have a second screen in libgdx

Tags: java, screen, libgdx

I have a very simple Libgdx game, its my first one, and in this game i have a main java file(obviously). This file extends Game and looks like this.

```
package com.jawdroppergames.penalty;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;

public class Penalty extends Game{


public MainGame main_screen;


@Override
public void create(){
    Assets.load();

    main_screen = new MainGame(this);
    setScreen(main_screen);
}

}
```

And in MainGame.java

```
private Penalty maingame;

public MainGame(Penalty game){
     this.maingame = game;

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(true,1080,1920);

    main_batch = new SpriteBatch();
    ball_batch = new SpriteBatch();
}
```

as well as more code obviously

This works perfectly and opens the MainGame class. Now what i want to do is open ANOTHER screen from within MainGame. Ive tried using the same code and changing the necessary names of files etc, and this calls the show method but doesnt render the actual screen, it calls show() but not render(). Any help?

oh, and MainScreen does extend Game

Answer (score 0):

this should work for u..

```
game.setScreen(new PlayScreen(game));//playscreen is the another screen
```

and why are you using two sprite batches, you should avoid this.

Comment: Sandeep i right never ever use two Sprite batch. Its very heavy object and nesting two sprite batch may give u improper results

Comment: i never used the second one! It's complicated why i have it but yeah... thanks for the great answer, ill try it tomorrow, dont have time now.

Comment: i've tried this but i'm not sure i understand. what is "game" set as?